# How to call a constructor with an ambiguous generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following generic class:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    //Constructor A
    public Foo(string str)
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }

    //Constructor B
    public Foo(T obj)
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}
```

I want to create an instance of this class with T being a `string`, using constructor B.

Calling `new Foo<string>("Hello")` uses constructor A. How can I call constructor B (without using reflection)?

Comment: Why not write your constructors to be less ambiguous?

Comment: @HereticMonkey This is a stripped-down scenario to illustrate the problem; I have a real need for a similar setup.

Comment: In case the type string is not used explicitly but a generic type is used there as well, constructor B would be used in all cases. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65939872/101087

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the two constructors use different names for the arguments, you can specify the name of the argument to choose the constructor to use:

```
new Foo<string>(str: "Test"); // Uses constructor A

new Foo<string>(obj: "Test"); // Uses constructor B
```

Answer (score 8):

It's horrible, but you could use a local generic method:

```cs
public void RealMethod()
{
    // This is where I want to be able to call new Foo<string>("Hello")

    Foo<string> foo = CreateFoo<string>("Hello");

    CreateFoo<T>(T value) => new Foo(value);
}
```

You could add that as a utility method anywhere, mind you:

```cs
public static class FooHelpers
{
    public static Foo<T> CreateFoo<T>(T value) => new Foo(value);
}
```

(I'd prefer the local method because this feels like it's rarely an issue.)

Comment: Hi Jon! That's a very nice solution. However, I went with NineBerry's approach as it seems more elegant.

Comment: @Bip901: Yup, that's neat - wish I'd thought of it :)